# Android Google Maps API v2 - how to change marker icon

Tags: android, google-maps, icons, google-maps-markers

I am trying to change marker icon.
I get the image from one server directory.

When I put break point every time the "bit" result is `null`. And when I run the app I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
File file = new File("J:\\!!! DOCUMENTS\\!Outsourcing\\AppStore\\Benzinostancii\\Petrol\\logo.png");

Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file));

double Dlat = lat.get(index);
double Dlon = lon.get(index);
String info = Arrayinfo.get(index);
String name = Arrayname.get(index);

LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(Dlat, Dlon);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bit))
    .position(coordinate)
    .title(info)
).setSnippet(name);
```

Comment: J directory is that in the internal memory of the android device? why not putting it in drawables?

Comment: This J directory is from PC server and I want to load the image from this server.

Comment: Oh I think that's not possible that way. You might want to download the image first from the server then use it.

Answer (score 85):

```
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = 17.385044;
double longitude = 78.486671;

// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

// Changing marker icon
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

[**More Info**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: I think you added a ) in your 9th lane

Comment: Might have meant `setIcon()`.

Comment: you sure setIcon works on new google apis ? i dont think so

Comment: This solution is no longer valide.

Comment: use `googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(35.699262, 51.345184)).title("your_title").icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.your_drawable)));`

Answer (score 19):

It's very simple :

```
new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon))
```

In case you want the icon from a bitmap

```
new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
```

Comment: Do you have a new solution? Submit an answer @DanAnderson

Comment: Well I didn't when I commented.  But I figured it out so I guess I could post it in case some one else, like me, finds this from a google search.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your icon?

Comment: 16 or 32 pixel is optimal dimension for markers ... nice view for all screens @Arjun

Answer (score 14):

Use `.icon()`
Add like this

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_place_holder)));
```

Please note don't use vector Images, if you want to use vector use below code

```
private BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptorFromVector(Context context, @DrawableRes  int vectorDrawableResourceId) {
    Drawable background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_map_pin_filled_blue_48dp);
    background.setBounds(0, 0, background.getIntrinsicWidth(), background.getIntrinsicHeight());
    Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, vectorDrawableResourceId);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(40, 20, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() + 40, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + 20);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(background.getIntrinsicWidth(), background.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    background.draw(canvas);
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In the newer versions of GoogleMaps for Android you can't call `.setIcon()` on a `MarkerOptions` object.    Instead you have to add the marker options to the map which will give you a `Marker` on which you can then change the icon.

In Kotlin the code would look like this:

```
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
markerOptions.position(LatLng(40.419900, -111.880767))
val marker: Marker?  = googleMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)
val bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_customer_symbol)
marker?.setIcon(bitmapDescriptor)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin C# users:

```
tappedMarker.Remove();
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.SetTitle(tappedMarker.Title);
markerOptions.SetPosition(tappedMarker.Position);

markerOptions.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.DefaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HueGreen));
tappedMarker = googleMap.AddMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: the method name never starts with an upper case. And these methods do not exist.

Comment: @Dennis well, it does on C#, but this is the Xamarin version, just convert the same code to java, same nomenclature

Comment: Okay, but these methods do not exist.

Comment: @Dennis, yes they do exist. Gustavo is talking c# Xamarin. This is how you have to address in c#.

Comment: oh, but we are talking about android -> JAVA here, he's not supposed to give answers in any other format right?

Comment: Sort of. It is the same subject, so whoever is looking for the same solution but in Xamarin version will find it. But the methods are the same name, just change SetTitle to setTitle and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Inside "onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)"

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable._icon));
```

Comment: You mean setIcon?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location);
            LatLng bangalore = new LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);

 MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(bangalore)
          .title("Current Location")
            .snippet("hello").icon(icon);


 mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: it won't work with xml files present in drawable. use png to get result

Answer (score 0):

```
   val marker = googleMap?.addMarker {
        position(LatLng(24.774265, 46.738586))
        title("Saudi Arabia")
        draggable(true)
        icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_address_location))
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      mMap = googleMap;
 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Lat,Lng);
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,12.0f));
```